# Buffer Overflow Attack

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, objdump

I'm trying to execute a very simple buffer overflow attack. I'm pretty much a newbie to this. So, if this question is stupid, please excuse me :-)

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int i, n;

void confused(int i) 
{
 printf("**Who called me? Why am I here?? *** %x\n ", i);
}

void shell_call(char *c) 
{
 printf(" ***Now calling \"%s\" shell command *** \n", c);
 system(c);
}

void victim_func()
{
 int a[4];
 printf("Enter n:  ");  scanf("%d",&n);
 printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~ values and address of n locations ~~~~~~~~~~");
 for (i = 0;i <n ;i++) 
  printf ("\n a[%d] = %x, address = %x", i, a[i], &a[i]);
 printf("\nEnter %d HEX Values \n", n);

 // Buffer Overflow vulnerability HERE!

 for (i=0;i<n;i++)  scanf("%x",&a[i]);
   printf("Done reading junk numbers\n");
}

int main() 
{
 victim_func();
 printf(“\n done”);
 return 0; 
}
```

When I use objdump to get the function addresses, I have the following:

```
main(): 0x804854d
Address of main() where printf() is called: 0x8048563
victim_func(): 0x8048455
confused(): 0x8048414
```

Now, what I want is to jump to the function 'confused()' from victim_func() by overflowing the buffer there, and overwriting the return address to the address of confused(). And I want to return back from confused() to the printf() statement in main, and exit normally. So, I provide the following input

```
Enter n: 7
Enter 7 HEX values:
1
2
3
4
5
8048414 (This is to jump to confused)
8048563 (this is to jump to printf() in main)
```

Although, the program prints "Done" from that printf statement, it is jumping back to victim_func() and prints "Enter n:"

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: I'm not sure if I have put the question right. Please let me know, if any more information is needed.

Comment: actually, this is an assignment at school!

Comment: If this is really homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: @VJo I think this is a great educational task - I'm tempted to try it myself: it requires a deep understanding and direct experimentation with the assembler implementation of the code. White hats need to grasp these ideas too.

Comment: LOL Which school teach how to misuse a buffer overflow? It is true that you need a deep understanding, but of a binary code. The attempt above is a pale attempt and is not going to work

Comment: @VJo: Acually, all computer security courses I've seen contain something like this. It is important to know how these attacks work, if nothing else then to get an understanding of why you should be careful when programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A buffer overflow attack is a lot more complex than this. First of all you need to understand assembler in order to perform this. After you disassemble the program and function you want to target you need to determine the stack layout when it's executing that function.
Here's a sample of a buffer overflow it's using visual studio but principle is the same.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>

volatile double  test;

double function3()
{
    test++;
    return exp(test);
}

double  function2()
{
    return log(test);
}

double  function1()
{
    int a[5] = {0};           
    a[7] = (int)&function3;
    return exp(function2());

}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double a = function1();
    test = a;
    return a;
}
```

Thanks to disassembly we know that a in function1 is allocated before where the function saved the stack frame pointer. The value after that one is the return address where function1 should go to if it is finished.

```
00401090 55               push        ebp    <- we save the stack pointer
00401091 8B EC            mov         ebp,esp 
00401093 83 EC 1C         sub         esp,1Ch <- save space to allocate a[5]
00401096 B8 CC CC CC CC   mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
0040109B 89 45 E4         mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],eax  <- crt debug init a[5]  
0040109E 89 45 E8         mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax 
004010A1 89 45 EC         mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax 
004010A4 89 45 F0         mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax 
004010A7 89 45 F4         mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax 
004010AA 89 45 F8         mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax 
004010AD 89 45 FC         mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax
```

From this we can conclude if we overwrite a[7] with a different address, the function will return not to main but with whatever address we wrote in a[7].

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the patient explanation. That's where I'm stuck! Why do we need to allocate 1Ch words, to store 5 words of the array? Could you please elaborate on the stack structure here?

Comment: And, this is a chunk of my disassembled main routine.
`0x0804855b <main+14>: sub    $0x4,%esp`
`0x0804855e <main+17>: call   0x8048455 <victim_func>`
`0x08048563 <main+22>: movl   $0x804872e,(%esp)`
`0x0804856a <main+29>: call   0x8048364 <printf@plt>`
    

So, I'm returning to main() at 0x8048563, from confused. There're no problems in putting the return address in the right memory location. And, main() resumes by printing "Done". But at this point, it goes back to the victim_func() and prints "Enter n:" This is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

> Now, what I want is to jump to the function 'confused()' from victim_func() by overflowing the buffer there, and overwriting the return address to the address of confused()...

On modern Linux platforms, you will also need to ensure two security features are turned off for testing. First in NX-stacks, and second is Stack Protectors.

To turn off NX-Stacks, use `-Wl,z,execstack` (as opposed to `-Wl,z,noexecstack`). To turn off Stack Protectors, use `-fno-stack-protector` (as opposed to `-fstack-protector` or `-fstack-protector-all`).

There's a third protection you might need to turn off. That protection is FORTIFY_SOURCE. FORTIFY_SOURCE uses "safer" variants of high risk functions like `memcpy` and `strcpy`. The compiler uses the safer variants when it can deduce the destination buffer size. If the copy would exceed the destination buffer size, then the program calls `abort()`. To disable FORTIFY_SOURCE, compile the program with `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` or `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`.

The security features are turned on by default because there's been so many problems in the past. In general, its a good thing because it stops many problems (like the one you are experimenting with).

Answer (score 1):

First of all it seems to me that you shouldn't enter the number 5 in your sample input. Your array is declared a[4] thus has elements indexed 0-3  - so your attack input seems wrong to me.

It also seems to me that your program assumes several thing about the architecture:

- sizof(int)==sizeof(memory address)
- The direction of growth and mechanism of the environments stack implementation

If one of these assumptions is untrue it's never going to work.

This seems like a very hard work work assignment.

There are easier examples of buffer overflow attacks than changing the control flow of the code. For example you might be able to overwrite another piece of data which is supposed to be protected from the user (such as a security setting)

Comment: Indexing beyond the bounds of the array is precisely how such attacks work.  And such attacks are always very platform dependent; they depend on how the stack is laid out, and generally involve some assembler.  The usual solution would be to put machine code which does something nefast in the buffer, then replace the return address on the stack with the address of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us the output of the program with the addresses of a[i]. I suspect that the compiler is doing something like aligning the data on the stack to 16. It could be much further to the return address than you expect.