# Why is it better to use `%s` to print a string using `printf` rather than printing it directly?

Tags: c, string, printf

I know that the declaration of `printf` is:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

This means that one can directly print a string instead of using `%s` and the string as an argument. See the following code:

```
char str[50];
char *ptr;
//initialize str and ptr

printf(str);  //BAD
printf(ptr);  //BAD
printf("%s",str);  //GOOD
printf("%s",ptr); //GOOD
```

I've read that printing the string directly as shown in the first two `printf`s is bad and one should always avoid doing that. Instead, using `%s` as shown in the last two `printf`s is better. Both of them prints the two strings correctly.

So, Why is it better to use `%s` to print a string using `printf` rather than printing it directly?
What are the problems that arises when one does not use `%s` to print a string using `printf`?

Comment: Think what will happen if your string contains `%`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459630/how-can-a-format-string-vulnerability-be-exploited

Comment: but `printf("Hello world!"); /* GOOD */`