# Segmentation fault using printf when the char pointer (strdup)

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, printf

I'm new to C-programming. I wrote a function

```
void fun (char** argv, int count, int loc);
```

In my function, I tried to create another array by doing

```
char** newray=strdup(argv).
```

When I tried to execute:

```
printf(newray[0])
```

I got a segmentation fault. I fixed it by doing

```
printf("%s\n", newray[0]).
```

However, to output the `argv[0]`, I only need to do this:

```
printf(argv[0]).
```

What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `argv` is not a string, it is an array of strings, so strdup is not a correct function to copy it. You need to do something along the lines of:

```c
newray = malloc(sizeof(char*) * argc);
for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++ i) newray[i] = strdup(argv[i]);
```

Where `argc` is the number of elements in `argv`. You will also need to free all the elements and then the array itself when you are done with it.

Comment: thanks for your response but my question is still not completely asked . Since argv is an array of strings , then argv[0] is String . my question is , why does printf(argv[0] ) work but newray[0] needs %s in order to print successfully? I think my questio. Is, what did strdup do to argv such That newray[0]  different from argv[0] although printf ("%s", newway[0] ) returns the same word aprintf(argv[0])?

Comment: There's no real difference in the two ways you are printing (as long as your string doesn't have % signs). How many times did you run your experiment? If just a couple, I would suggest that you got lucky when you were printing directly, and unlucky when you were printing using `%s`. Try running both of them couple more times.

Comment: Also, are you sure you did `printf("%s\n", newray[0])`, not `printf("%s\n", newray)`?

Comment: @Armin , See [Why is it better to use `%s` to print a string using `printf` rather than printing it directly?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28064827/why-is-it-better-to-use-s-to-print-a-string-using-printf-rather-than-printi)