# Two possibilities to print a string with printf

Tags: c, printf

Task: Write two possibilities printf commands to print the following char array.

```
char str[] = "Im a sentence";
```

I found out one:

```
printf("%s", str) // this prints: Im a sentence
```

But i need another one, can anyone help me?

Comment: You can print string character by character.

Comment: yes, with a loop, but it should be just one printf line.

Comment: printf it is not a command, it is a function

Comment: you can use `fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", str);`

Comment: `printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c",str[0],str[1],str[2],str[3],str[4],str[5],str[6],str[7],str[8],str[9],str[10],str[11],str[12]);` would be the third way.

Comment: `printf("%s", &str[0]);`

Comment: you can `write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, strlen(str));`

Comment: @IvanIvanovich _print a string with printf_

Comment: `for (p=str; *p != '\0'; p++) {printf("%c", *p);}`

Comment: If you are wondering why the method in @dasblinkenlight's answer and PaulR's answer is not a good practice, then read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459630/how-can-a-format-string-vulnerability-be-exploited)

Comment: @AlterMann I think 'printf("%s", &str[0]);' is the right one.

Comment: `printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%s",str[0],str[1],str[2],str[3],str[4],str[5],str[6],str[7],str[8],str[9],str[10],str[11],str+12);` would be the fourth way.

Comment: `printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%s",str[0],str[1],str[2],str[3],str[4],str[5],s​tr[6],str[7],str[8],str[9],str[10],str+11);` fifth. see, c is a very flexible language!

Answer (score 3):

It's a silly question, but they are probably looking for this:

```
printf(str);       // 1
printf("%s", str); // 2
```

Note that (1) is not considered good practice, but it is valid and it works.

Comment: yeah, 1 should be avoided if `str` can be manipulated by the user.

Answer (score 3):

The other one would be passing the string directly to `printf`:

```
printf(str);
```

As long as `str` is free of format specifiers, this is going to work. However, you should avoid using this in production code, because the compiler would be unable to properly diagnose potential mismatches between parameter types and format specifiers, which could lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x;
for (x=0;x<strlen(str);++x) 
    printf("%c",str[x]);
```

Comment: `for ( int x = 0; x < sizeof(str); x++)` I think would be better

Comment: As far as i know, we should not use a loop.

Comment: Or `for (x = 0; str[x] != '\0'; ++x)`

Comment: @tema, `sizeof(*str)` is always 1, you mean `sizeof(str)`

Comment: Thanks, i take this as 3rd possibility.