# Two ways to print a string with printf

Tags: c, printf

```
char zk[] = "All is great";
```

I have to write two possibilities printf commands to print out all is great, starting from third position. I have following:

```
1. 
    printf("%s\n", &zk[2]);
2.
    for (int x = 2; x < strlen(zk); x++) printf("%c", zk[x]);
```

Both working for me, but I think i have to avoid a for loop, and just use the print command, is there any other way to print out All is great from the third position?

Comment: @Cool Guy &Alter Mann edited.

Comment: Strings traditionally go into `char` arrays, too, not `int` arrays...

Comment: Can you define how it's "working for you", because I get both `error: array of inappropriate type initialized from string constant` and `warning: passing argument 1 of 'printf' from incompatible pointer type`?

Comment: @Jongware which variant #1 or #2 ?

Comment: All the variants that contained your original line `int zk[] = "All is great";`. The error and warning were issued by gcc, using `-pedantic -Wall` ("Check strictly, and everything is an error"); I'd strongly recommend to look up similar settings for your own setup.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%s", string + offset)
```

And it will print your string starting from position `offset`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string as the first argument:

```
printf(&zk[2]);
```

This is ok as long as the string doesn't contain a `%`. Why? Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459630/how-can-a-format-string-vulnerability-be-exploited) to know it.

Comment: I kow but this time i have to start from the third position.