# Can I change an initialized char pointer via function?

Tags: c, pointers

This is my `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changeStuff(char *stuff){
    stuff=  "Hello everyone";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *stuff;
    changeStuff(stuff);
    printf(stuff);
    return 0;
}
```

When I build this, I get this warning:

```
warning: ‘stuff’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

When I run this program, nothing is printed.

Since it does not seem possible to define a `char*` with no value after it has been declared, how do I change the value of a `char*` passed to a function?

Comment: No, you are only changing the local copy of the pointer that was passed, which will be forgotten.

Comment: C uses pass-by-value. `f(x)` can't change `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, function arguments are passed-by-value. In order to modify a pointer value, you need to pass a pointer to the pointer, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changeStuff(char **stuff){
    *stuff=  "Hello everyone";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *stuff;
    changeStuff(&stuff);
    printf("%s\n", stuff);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that it's not a good idea to directly pass user-defined values to `printf()`. See: [How can a Format-String vulnerability be exploited?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7459630/1275169)

Comment: One question. Is passing by reference -- &stuff -- the same as passing a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: there is no pass-by-reference in C (only in C++)

Comment: C doesn't have pass by reference at all. `&stuff` is still passed by value (except that you can use that value to modify its pointee).

Comment: Ah, it's pass by address. In this case, is there a difference between what is represented by `char **stuff` and `&stuff`?

Comment: `char *stuff` is a pointer. `&stuff` is the address of the pointer itself. `char **stuff` is pointer to a pointer. The function writes to `*stuff` so it changes the pointer, because it was passed the *address* of a pointer.